# Which release of ICU works best with Visual Studio Express 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, icu

The ICU 4.6 has versions for download for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, but not for Visual Studio 2008. I'm using 2008 Express because it seems to be a little more free than the 2010 version and because there is a free download of MSDN that works with 2008 but not so for 2010 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The previous release of ICU was 4.4 but that only provides a download for "Visual Studio 9". Now I can't find info on this Visual Studio 9 on either Microsoft's site or Wikipedia. Could it perhaps be that 9 is the version of the C/C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2008 or is it some even older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a VS2010 express: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP

VS9 probably means 2008, check the ICU readme to be sure.

In any event, if you use cygwin you can build ICU from an older MSVC version.

I'd really recommend the latest ICU.

Comment: I think you missed my two reasons for using Visual Studio Express 2008. I've read and Googled the ICU online docs many times but still can't find confirmation that VS9 means Visual Studio 2008. I've used cygwin many times in the past but for my current project using the native tools on Windows is one of my goals.

Comment: @hippietrail  vs9=visual studio 2008. We probably should have made that more clear. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Msvc#32-bit_versions   As well, I'm told (I have not tried this personally, but hope to soon) that vs2010 can target vs2008 runtime with the right settings .So you could build with 2010 but produce binaries that can build with 2008.   I'm sorry, I misread your comment about MSDN. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Steven that helps a lot! (-:

Comment: "...if you use cygwin you can build ICU from an older MSVC version." -- how?

Comment: @DevSolar http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/readme.html#HowToBuildCygwin (or in your current icu version)